# vscode is not running and gives segmentation fault

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, segmentation-fault

Just updated form vscode 1.23.1 to 1.27.2
I cannot open form menu so I tried from  terminal it shows the segmentation error.
`/usr/bin/code: line 35:  8228 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 "$ELECTRON" "$CLI" "$@"`

[Terminal View for fault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHOcZ.png)

- VSCode Version: 1.27.2-1536736588
- OS Version: Ubuntu Budgie Cosmic Cuttlefish (development branch) (18.10)

Does this issue occur when all extensions are disabled?: Yes

[When all the extensions are disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPtYp.png)

EDIT: The issues are solved for this problem in VS-code stable version.
install the [latest stable version](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this problem for months and after researching I'm still unaware why this problem occurs.I guessed this might be a problem related to glibc version(as I'm using ubuntu 18.10 and it uses an updated version of glibc).For temporary solution you can install electron via npm and launch code by typing `electron resources/app` as referred [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/51917#issuecomment-412726390).Alternatively you can use [vscode exploration](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/52629) instead of insiders.By using vscode via electron was using a bit too much memory on my machine,so I prefer using the latter one.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on Ubuntu-20 and VScode-1.62.
As a solution, I only downloaded [installation file](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) and installed it. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Running!,
problem:
I have tried deleting and reinstalling code-oss several time still it was giving the segmentation fault in terminal while opening and closes immediately and also not opening directly too.
solution: reinstall the packages from visual studio code official docs step by step then it will run:
Note:
(perform all the commands as a root user)

1- `wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > packages.microsoft.gpg`

2- `sudo apt install apt-transport-https`

3- `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'`

4- `apt-get install code`

5- `apt update`

now, it you use the program :)